# Can setting the date on your iPhone to the epoch really brick it?

Tags: iphone, timestamp, time

So, I've started seeing warnings that there is a troll/hoax saying that people should set the date on their phone to 1st January 1970 to get a retro logo to display.

The warnings say that this will end up bricking your phone, and even a reset of the phone won't help.

Is the warning about bricking well-founded? What is this exploit and how could/should it have been prevented?

Comment: Seems real to me. Also doesn't seem on topic for this site. http://www.snopes.com/apples-blast-from-the-past/

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of a question on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227394/cause-of-unix-epoch-time-integer-underflow)

Answer (score 3):

It's real, sadly. From [Wired article](http://www.wired.com/2016/02/dont-set-your-iphone-back-to-1970-no-matter-what/):

> The bug appears to **only affect 64-bit iOS devices**, meaning **iPhone 5S, iPad Air, and iPad Mini 2 and newer** are affected. It’s almost certainly related to the same Unix glitch that caused Facebook to wish people a happy 46 years on the service; the date 1/1/70 has an internal value of zero on a Unix system, which in this case is leading to a software freakout.